# How do I get new ssh-keys (linux 20.04) into a secure server (linux 20.04) with no root access and fail2ban and Google auth

Tags: linux, ssh, security

What do I need to do to get new ssh-keys into my linux 20.04 servers with no root access, fail2ban and Google auth installed.

I bought a new computer and want to access everything from there. I made new keys but it says invalid format.
or permission denied.

Is there anyway to simply do this without having to disable all the security.. I'm looking for a simple hack here to get the key.pub file in and setup. All attempts have failed currently. I have made new keys, dropped them into the Authorized_key file and restarted the ssh service. I really don't know what else I might need to do..

I put my keys in a different directory.. but I launch the ssh -p 1234 user@ipaddress command in the directory holding the keys.

please any tips would be great, or maybe just let me know, I need to undo all my security first before I can make it work.. Any quick tips would be really appriciated.. Thanks

Comment: Try `ssh -i /path/to/private_key -p 1234 user@ipaddress`.

Comment: You don't need root to add a key to ssh where you can log in as a normal user, nor do you need to restart  SSH. The location, spelling AND CASE of .authorized_keys is important.  What error do you get when you try log in? (I wonder if the issue is your public key or a different machine fingerprint...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to at least one user on the server you can user ssh-copy-id. Type `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/your/key username@server` and it should copy your key to the server.